# Can't turn off display of php errors on app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

display_errrors seems to be stuck with a On value. When I look at phpinfo it says its on and the default is Off. When I add my own php.ini to the root of the app with display_errors = Off it still shows as On. I can change other values like upload_max_filesize and see the changes in phpinfo but I can't turn errors off. Running app_engine_release 1.9.3

Problem only appears for admin users that for the google apps account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now this is by design - for app admins we turn display_errors on. The idea being that if your an admin of the app and you app has errors you want to see them so you can fix them.

Accessing the app through an incognito window to see what you're users would see should have display_errors set to off.

Comment: I was testing Wordpress 3.9 RC1 and all the ajax requests were failing because of the errors being displayed. I haven't noticed this before on our other WP site and not sure where the exact problem is yet. Any plans to make this optional in the future?

Comment: best to file a feature request if you think making this optional is worthwhile ... but isn't it better to fix things so that there are no errors in the first place?